# Dúvida no método VerifyUserTokenAsync do Asp.Net Core Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

Estou com uma dúvida em relação ao ***VerifyUserTokenAsync*** do ***Asp.Net Core Identity***

Caso o usuário esqueça a senha, forneço uma página para ele indicar o e-mail e envio uma url que possui o **UserId** e **Token** (da forma padrão):

```
private async Task EsqueciMinhaSenhaAsync(EsqueciMinhaSenhaViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);

    if (user != null)
    {
        var token = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
        var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ResetarSenha", "Auth", new { userId = user.Id, token = token}, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

        //TODO: enviar e-mail
    }

}
```

Quando o usuário acessar a url gerada, irei chamar o seguinte trecho de código (que verifica se o ***token*** é válido, caso não, irei redirecionar através da controller avisando que a solicitação foi expirada, por exemplo):

```
public async Task<bool> VerificarTokenValidoAsync(ApplicationUser user, string token)
{    
    return await _userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, string.Empty, "ResetPassword", token))      
}
```

Minha dúvida está no método ***VerificarTokenValidoAsync***, utilizo ele para verificar se o ***token*** é válido antes de dar o acesso da página onde o usuário irá fornecer uma nova senha, porém, ele recebe no **segundo parâmetro** (onde deixei **string.Empty**), um tal de ***tokenProvider***, gostaria de saber do que se trata esse parâmetro e como faço para gerá-lo.

### Atualização 01/03/2018

Consegui utilizar o método, existe uma classe (**TokenOptions**) onde fornece o *providerToken* padrão:

```
_userManager.VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, TokenOptions.DefaultProvider, proposito, token)
```

Desta forma, funcionou corretamente, porém, o único problema agora é que o resultado sempre retorna ***false***.

Comment: esse parametro é quando vc cria um token personalizado, então você tem  que passar o provider para o servidor conseguir interpretar e verificar se o token é valid ou não >> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-custom-security-token-provider

Comment: Entendi, o único problema é que não vou precisar usar isso, mas jogando string.Empty no parâmetro dá um erro. Sabe me informar se existe alguma forma de executar este método sem utilizar este token ?

Comment: tentou passar null ?

Comment: Pior que nulo também dá uma problema: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: tokenProvider. Tudo bem, vou ver se dou uma pesquisada hoje a noite, caso eu ache alguma solução ou problema no sistema, atualizo informando. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Ele vem da configuração do seu identity no seu startup.cs:

```
// ASP.NET Core Identity Configuration
            services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

São tokens providers padrões do ASP.NET Core. No seu caso de email use:

```
var tokenProvider = Options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider;
return await VerifyUserTokenAsync(user, tokenProvider, "ResetPassword", token);
```